# R grep sublist from master list from dataframe

Tags: r, list

How to grep a sublist of a list like grep -f in unix?
say I have a dataframe

```
A 1 3 4 
B 4 5 6
C 7 8 9
D 1 3 4
E 1 3 3
F 2 4 5
```

and I  only need

```
A 1 3 4 
C 7 8 9
E 1 3 3
F 2 4 5
```

by like `grep c(A C E F)` ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the `A` `C` `E` `F` are rownames. Assumming that your data frame is called `dd`, basic subsetting should do the trick:

```
##Select rows where the rownames are in a particular vector
dd[rownames(dd) %in% c("A", "C", "E", "F"), ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I want go one step further as the dataframe is 128 columns with 105k rows(128 x 105k), and my rownames ID is 3500 saved in a  different file "subsetID.txt". How do I retrieve the subset of the dataframe? Thanks again!

Comment: Wish there is a way to combine all answers together! I was trying to grep a vector/column from another file, which is the subset of colnames of my dataframe. subset<-read.table("list.tab", header=F)

dfrm[grepl(subset[,1], dfrm[,1]), ]  But did not go thru. Any clue? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `A..F` are from column `V1`, you can use `grepl` which returns `TRUE/FALSE`:

```
# gives TRUE when V1 != B, D
df[grepl("[^BD]", df$V1), ]

#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  A  1  3  4
# 3  C  7  8  9
# 5  E  1  3  3
# 6  F  2  4  5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly the cases that are A, C, E or F in the first column and need to use `grep` then:

```
 dfrm[ grep("^[ACEF]$", dfrm[,1]), ]
```

If those letters were rownames then use `rownames(dfrm)` instead of `dfrm[,1]`

To create new object:

```
 newobj <- dfrm[ grep("^[ACEF]$", dfrm[,1]), ]
```

To your comment: To save as an R object to later `load` into a session:

```
 save( newobj , file='newobj_file.rda')
```

To save as a text file:

```
 write.table( newobj, file='newobj_out.txt')
```

See ?write.table for various option on that and see the Import/Export Manual for much more background. It is part of your R installation. Use your help facilities. On my machine it is located in the R directories as : .... /doc/manual/R-data.html

Comment: Thanks! I need one further step for sublist saved in a file.

Comment: Do you mean you need an example of how to create a new object with this result?   `newobj <- dfrm[ grep("^[ACEF]$", dfrm[,1]), ]`

Comment: No, I mean "^[ACEF]$" is actually a vector from another file, which is the subset of colnames of dfrm. Thanks!

Comment: So they are not single letters? Do your really need to use `grep`? Please make an example that illustrates a reasonable approximation to the problem to be solved.

Comment: No, I mean "^[ACEF]$" is actually a vector from another file, which is the subset of colnames of dfrm. subset<-read.table("list.tab", header=F)

dfrm[grepl(subset[,1], dfrm[,1]), ]  But did not go thru. Any clue? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. The clue is to NOT use `grepl`.

Comment: grep is the clue I could think of. There must be a way for R to do the this job. Right?

Comment: Sigh. Yes. Please look at cgillespie's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DWin and csgillespie! The trick is the vector that I should pay more attention.

```
>dfrm
A 1 3 4 
B 4 5 6
C 7 8 9
D 1 3 4
E 1 3 3
F 2 4 5
```

and my list of the interest is stored in a file

```
subset <-read.table("infile", header=F)
>subset
1 A
2 C
3 E
4 F
> dfrm[rownames(dfrm) %in% subset[,1], ]
A 1 3 4 
C 7 8 9
E 1 3 3
F 2 4 5
```

I should have known that subset is a data frame, too. subset[,1] played the trick.  Thank you csgillespie!